# How do I adjust default "before paragraph" setting in keynote?

Tags: keynote

When I add a new slide in keynote, the "before paragraph" setting is set to 46. How do I change this default?

I can adjust this setting by selecting the text on the slide and changing "before paragraph" to 0; but, I don't want to have to do this for every slide.